# How to debug common table expressions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I had a problem in a query, where one of CTEs returned no rows. But this was hard to notice, and debugging lastet quite a while.

**Is it possible to output all CTEs in Postgres without commenting out the main query**?

```
create or replace function generate_grid(
    poly geometry, step double precision)
    returns setof geometry as
$$ */

with 
    initial as (select st_xmin(poly) x0, st_ymin(poly) y0),
    ...(another 3 CTE skipped here)...
    grid as (select point from points where st_intersects(point, poly)),
    centroid as (select st_centroid(poly) point from grid where (select count(*)=0 from grid))
select * from grid
union all
select * from centroid;
$$ language sql;
```

In the example, CTE `centroid` was incrementally added to the function which worked well before. It should return rows in case `grid` is empty. The bug (**which I have fixed**) was that it didn't, because it selected from the empty CTE `grid`. Now when I described the problem it's obvious why it failed, but when you write it and debug, all sorts of things may happen, like mixed geometries SRID, wrong SRID, etc.

Comment: Why would you write such a thing in the first place, if you don't know what it does?

Comment: @joop when you accidentally make a bug, you always know what your program does. It's a small detail that you're missing that makes things not work. I added the real query I worked with.

Comment: `... from grid where (select count(*)=0 from grid))` is just bad style, which can be avoided, IMHO. [ I don't even know if it is valid syntax; I'd use a `NOT EXISTS()` construct here IIUC the fragment]

Comment: @joop good point, forgot about that clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXPLAIN ANALYZE looks to report the CTEs separately.

When I run that (Postgresql 9.4) it is showing the CTEs separately, and in the result section it does show that the actual number of rows returned from "CTE Scan on x" was 0.

```
explain analyze
with x as (select 1 where false),
     y as (select 2 where true)
select * from x, y;
```

Returns:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.02..0.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: x."?column?", y."?column?"
  CTE x
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
          Output: 1
          One-Time Filter: false
  CTE y
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (never executed)
          Output: 2
  ->  CTE Scan on x  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: x."?column?"
  ->  CTE Scan on y  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)
        Output: y."?column?"
Planning time: 0.034 ms
Execution time: 0.018 ms
```

I don't know the explain would always display data like this, I suspect it depends on how Postgresql decides to optimize the query, but it should be a good start point.

Explain documentation at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `CROSS JOIN` is that it would produce no output when one of derived tables is empty:

```
with x as (select 1 where false),
     y as (select 2 where true)
select * from x, y;
```

You need something like **`OUTER CROSS JOIN`**.

In `SQL Server` there is great `OUTER APPLY`:

```
with x(c) as (select 1 where 1=0),
     y(d) as (select 2 where 1=1)
select * 
FROM (values ('Base')) AS s(val)   -- always one row
OUTER APPLY x
OUTER APPLY y;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/YVLYK13274)**</kbd>

You could simulate this behaviour using `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`, but it looks a bit "ugly":

```
;WITH x(c) AS (SELECT 1 WHERE false),
      y(d) AS (SELECT 2 WHERE true)
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('Base row')) AS s(val)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM x) AS x(c) ON true
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM y) AS y(d) ON true;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/7547/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══╗
║   val     ║   c     ║ d ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══╣
║ Base row  ║ (null)  ║ 2 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══╝
```

or simple `LEFT JOIN` in this case:

```
;WITH x(c) AS (SELECT 1 WHERE false),
     y(d) AS (SELECT 2 WHERE true)
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('Base row')) AS s(val)
LEFT JOIN x ON true
LEFT JOIN y ON true;
```

Comment: I just made a sample query, of course I know it makes 0 rows. But the tool is very interesting, thanks!

Comment: Hint: `select * from x full join y on true`